# What the "+" and "-" buttons do in Pantheon-files (files manager in Elementary OS)?

Tags: files, file-manager, elementary-os

When setting the view to "Grid"  in Pantheon Files (Elementary OS), there is this option to click a "+" or "-" button on folders and files.

What is that?

[image]

After clicking the "+", this may be switched back:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you can select many files with that feature (same that with for example gnome's file manager you can select multiple files by holding ctrl and then clicking multiple files). I haven't tested that so I could be wrong also.

Comment: yes indeed. as the other answer also states, this is about selecting files: "+" selects and "-" un-selects the file or folder. as this was posted first i'll set it as the definitive answer

Answer (score 0):

This is for selecting multiple files (at least in KDE), its useful if you are using single click for opening files, which is enabled by default.

You can read more about this [here](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management#Introduction_to_Dolphin).

Comment: true. i will set as definitive the other earlier answer though